# HTML2 Canvas drawing dashed line in a loop

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Can somebody explain me why lines doesn't look similar to each other?

[image]

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
ctx.setLineDash([10,10]);
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  ctx.moveTo(0, 300/5 * i);
  ctx.lineTo(500, 300/5 * i);
}
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
#canvas { border: 1px solid #eaeaea}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"/>
```

Comment: Try not beginning and closing the path. Just draw them lines.

Comment: Without beginPath and closePath it looks better, but first line still looks different

Comment: That's because you're drawing it on y coordinate 0, and half it gets cut off.

Comment: Thanks Chris, you are right!